# How to make a standalone application with resources inside in python?

Tags: python, windows, compilation, python-standalone

I need to make an application consisting of exactly one exe file, with resources inside (pictures and fonts). The problem is that I write in pure Python, and I don’t know if there're compilers for Python that can pack resources into exe. Please recommend one if you know.

P.S. It's advisable for the compiler to optimize, i.e. that's doesn't drag all the libraries into exe, but took only necessary ones. I'm very afraid that the compiled executable will slow down.

Comment: This is way too broad for a SO question. What you want is probably not a true compiler, but an embedded Python interpretor. You should google for py2exe and/or pyinstaller for some tools able to build that. BTW, if you want to build a GUI app having resources, PyQt or PySide could also be nice (but heavy...) tools.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I don’t care how the executable actually works, as long as it’s not too slow.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this website: https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/, or Google how to pack images into pyinstaller.